Como programar una subida de imagen en VB para asp.net
Estoy de practicas y me han encargado añadirle funcionalidades a una web. La verdad que es un lio porque es enorme y el back está ya compilado. Debo de crearles un boton para que peudan añadir imagenes a la web y se alojen en una carpeta, pero claro, como no puedo tocar el back, constantemente me saltan errores de alli, asi que trato de programarlo todo en VB en el front, se me hace practicamente imposible... Existe alguna forma de poder hacerlo esquivando el back? La logica de mi codigo actual era esta y me salta error con el back:
 <% 
If IsPostBack Then
    If fileUploadImage.HasFile Then
        Try
            Dim fileExtension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileUploadImage.FileName)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension) AndAlso (fileExtension.Equals(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse fileExtension.Equals(".jpeg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse fileExtension.Equals(".png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) Then
                Dim fileName As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + fileExtension
                Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/img/") + fileName
                fileUploadImage.SaveAs(filePath)
                lblMessage.Text = "Imagen subida correctamente."
                lblMessage.Visible = True
                imgUploaded.ImageUrl = "~/img/" + fileName
                imgUploaded.Visible = True
            Else
                lblMessage.Text = "Formato de archivo no válido."
                lblMessage.Visible = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblMessage.Text = "Ocurrió un error al subir la imagen: " + ex.Message
            lblMessage.Visible = True
        End Try
    Else
        lblMessage.Text = "Por favor, seleccione un archivo."
        lblMessage.Visible = True
    End If

    If Request.Params.Count > 0 Then
        Try
            spanErrorCode.InnerText = Request.Params(0).Substring(0, Math.Min(Request.Params(0).Length, 3))
        Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            ' Maneja la excepción aquí
            spanErrorCode.InnerText = "Código de error no disponible"
        End Try
    Else
        spanErrorCode.InnerText = "Código de error no disponible"
    End If
End If
%>

Luego los botones tenian esta forma:
 <form class="m-0" id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadImage" runat="server" />
     <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Subir Imagen" />
     <hr />
     <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
 </form>

Alguien con mas conocimientos? muchas gracias

si no podes tocar el back, y el front esta del lado del usuario, quien se supone reciba el archivo y lo ponga en el servidor??? es muy raro lo que decis...

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
